# Why create a subkey in the digital signature algorithm

Tags: dsa

In the signing step, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm#Signing), a subkey is created.

```
A key k is randomly chosen from 1..q-1.
```

What's the use of that k?

If the k is to make less exposure to the private x; however, x is inevitably used in the signing part when computing s.

Comment: That's not a subkey. That's simply the randomness used in the signing process.

Comment: I guess any answer that explains the reason for $k$ would suffice. I think we can agree with Maeher that $k$ is not a subkey. Something about security and calculation of the private key giving separate signatures, I predict.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the use of that k?

The following lines of the wiki tell you:

Compute $r := ( g^k \bmod p  )  \bmod    q$

Compute $s := ( k^{−1} ( H(m) + xr  ) ) \bmod    q$

That is, it is used to compute both $r$ and $s$.

However, that's not what your really asking.  You're asking "why did they design DSA that way?"

Well, it's actually a variation on a noninteractive [Schnorr proof of knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_knowledge#Schnorr_protocol) of a discrete log (in particular, of the private key); the modifications are there to reduce the size of the signature.

And, since Schnorr requires a "commitment" (what you call a subkey), well, so does DSA